# A Physics Linear motion homework question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity, projectile

> A diver in the Olympics jumps off the 10 m platform. His initial velocity upward is 4 m/s.
>
> Determine the time until he hits the water?

I'm confused and would like someone to assist me with working it out. Do I start with the displacement formula or Final Velocity formula? I think it is displacement, but I have trouble getting to the point where I can use the quadratic formula to solve the quadratic I'm left with.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

As it's for homework, I wouldn't solve it, but I just let you know what to do.
This problem can be divided into two parts.

1. Time taken till his final velocity is zero while moving up.
2. Time taken for drop from that height into water.

It can be done in other ways too, but the most convenient way to do it is, find the time of flight  till he reaches the highest point. Obviously final velocity when he reaches the max. height is 0.

Find the height he has gone up from the platform and add 10 into it and then calculate the free drop from that height.

In first equation you have $v_i = 4 v_f=0$ and a is due to gravity, so $a=g$ you need to find $t$ and then $h.$

$$v_f=v_i+at_1$$
 or $$t_1=v_i/a$$ ruling out the negative sign for time.

for height

use $$v_f^2 - v_i^2 = 2gh$  as $v_f = 0$ so it reduces to

$$h= v_i^2/2g$$

Total height $H = h+10$

In second one you have height and acceleration. Initial velocity is 0, so it's easy to find time.

$$H=v_i\cdot t+1/2a\cdot t_2^2$$

as $v_i$ here is $0,$ because the diver has reached the highest point.

$H=1/2gt_2^2$ or $t_2=\sqrt{(2H/g)}\,.$

Total time = $t_1+t_2$

If you have any doubts, comment and I'll help further, but show me the progress you have made so far.

Comment: Well, I'm quite happy to see you didn't provide a complete answer to the homework problem. Anyways, this is a MathJax-enabled site. For quick reference, check this Meta Math.SE [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @MAFIA36790.  Absolutely, giving away answers is not going to help them in anyway. Thanks for the pointer, I'll use the feature in future.

Comment: yes, and that must be the attitude to answer such queries where OP doesn't even show minimal effort. We are not Yahoo! after all.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the formula :     vf^2- vi^2=2ad, where d is displacement from initial to final. In our case it is -10 m ( initially at +10 finally at 0 = water level). Also in our case a=-g, so vf^2=4^2+2(-g)(-10) or vf=14.56 m/s. Of course this velocity is DOWN, so we must take it with minus sign!
Now we apply formula vf=vi+at.
In our case it look like
-14.56=+4-9.8t, therefore t= (4+14.56)/9.8=1.89 sec.

Comment: Please don't provide complete answers to homework questions. also, do use Mathjax; it's a mathjax-enabled site. for quick reference, check this Meta Math.SE [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).